# smtpclient.send kills session in IIS but not Visual Studio debug

Tags: vb.net, smtp, iis-7.5, visual-studio-debugging

I'm having trouble with my website where calls to send email are killing the user's session but I have no idea how or why.

The site runs VB.NET code in aspx pages hosted on IIS 7.5. When the users gets to the point where it calls smtpclient.send, it abruptly kicks them out to the login page, doesn't send the email, and doesn't always finish what it was doing at the time (such as creating records). It doesn't give them an error and I haven't been able to find any errors in the logs. However if I run the site from a Windows 7 desktop with Visual Studio's debugger, everything runs perfectly.

I've tried deploying a second copy of the site on the same server and it has the exact same problem. Unfortunately I don't have easy access to a second IIS server to see if it could be a setting specific to my server.

This is a problem that only started occurring over a month ago. Before that, the site was reliable and rarely had any problems.

The code involved is pretty simple but for the sake of troubleshooting I reduced it to just the basics. Still functional at debug and crashing in production.

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage()

mail.From = New MailAddress("myemail@example.com")
mail.To.Add("myemail@example.com")
mail.Subject = "Subject Line test"
mail.Body = "This is the test body"

Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("mail.example.com")
smtp.Send(mail)
```

Does anyone have any idea of what could be going wrong or how I could at least get an error code to work from?

Comment: Sharing the code (and any configuration) associated with where the failure occurs will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a website from a basic template and adding only the smtp code, I finally got an error message that explained what was going on. It was an exception caused by unrelated issues at our mail server. When the exception would occur, this error would be caught and attempt to email the error log to the admin ... by calling the original send email function.